# USA documentation requirements for minor travelling on their own

Tags: usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, minors

My 17-year-old son is a dual US-UK citizen and is travelling to the USA this summer on his own. I have been told U.S. Customs and Border Protection (CBP) recommends that the child carries a notarized written consent letter from both parents, in case it is requested for review by US immigration officials.

- Does anyone have a link to an example letter to show what this should look like?
- Does he need to bring an original of his birth certificate or any other documents?
- Also, regarding the  notarization, does this have to be done as per US guidelines or UK guidelines? I understood that in the UK the equivalent of US notarization would be a solicitor's/lawyer's signature witnessing the signatures or for example having this done by a bank. Would this be sufficient, as the cost of having something notarized in the UK is quite expensive.

Many thanks.

Comment: @TheZealot I would be less sanguine. Under the Hague Convention, I don't think minor children have a right to enter the USA over the objections of parents or a custodial parent.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus the Hague Convention says nothing about entering countries or crossing borders.  A border crossing is just a convenient point for identifying children who have been wrongfully removed from someone's custody.

Comment: @phoog Agreed. My point is showing up without permission documentation is a good way to get invited to an extended secondary screening. If it's a child-napping in progress, I don't see admission into the USA as happening. There have been cases where USA citizen minors were forcibly repatriated with their non-citizen parents who were leaving voluntarily. I don't think a USA passport is any guarantee that a _minor_ will be admitted if there is reason to think a custodial parent does not want that to happen.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I imagine rather that they would admit the child for the purpose of immigration law, take the child from the custody of the person in whose wrongful custody the child was, and then return the child to his or her rightful custodian.  Wherever they keep the child in the meanwhile, it would certainly not be in immigration detention.

Comment: Probably time to stop speculating, but we have lots of immigration detention centers for children.

Comment: If you're worried about the UK notarization being accepted stateside, you can get the FCO to legalize (apply an apostille to) the notary/solicitor's signature: https://www.gov.uk/get-document-legalised This confirms to overseas authorities that they're a legit notary/solicitor.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus it is not speculation when I say that the federal government has no authority under immigration law to detain US citizens.

Comment: @phoog But it does have authority to act _in loco parentis_. [Example where](http://www.cnn.com/2011/OPINION/03/23/navarrette.child.deported/index.html) 4 year old USA citizen was going to be placed in a child detention facility when visa of accompanying non-citizen grandparent was found to be invalid. I suggest (a) we take this to chat and (b) you come up with some cases where minors were admitted under these or similar circumstances while adult was not.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I have no ability to find cases of that sort. All I know is that it is fundamental in the operation of US immigration law that as soon as the immigration inspector accepts that a person is a US citizen, the immigration interview is over and the person must be admitted to the country. See also page 252 of the [field manual](https://www.shusterman.com/pdf/cbpinspectorsfieldmanual.pdf) ("follow local port procedures governing United States citizens who may be in violation of federal or state law"). I don't have anything else to say about this, so there's no point in going to chat.

Answer (score 3):

thanks for your feedback, he has a US and UK passport.

In the meantime I've had a reply from CPB:

Thank you for contacting U.S. Customs and Border Protection’s (CBP) Information Center.

CBP strongly recommends that unless a child is accompanied by both parents, provide a letter which states you are giving him permission to travel by himself internationally. Letter from the child's other parent or parents stating: "I acknowledge that my son/daughter is traveling out of the country . He/She has/have my permission to do so”. The letter should include Who, What, Where, When, Why, and contact information for the absent parent(s). Having the letter notarized is not necessary but is highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

These regulations are in place to stop interference with custody orders, and I suppose runaways although that is a little hard to worry about for an airfare. A 17-year-old who can answer questions about his home life and travel plans is a small risk. I think a witnessed letter would be ample. My younger child was never asked anything at all, although he was armed with a US Notarized letter.